# sparse matrix solver runs out of memory in parallaleized dynamic LCA

Tags: brightway

I am trying to parallelize a few dynamic LCA (just something like 10...while I should run more than thousand...) and I got this

```
Can't expand MemType 1: jcol 19852
Can't expand MemType 0: jcol 17930
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/giuseppec/miniconda3/envs/bw2/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/home/giuseppec/miniconda3/envs/bw2/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 47, in starmapstar
    return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
  File "multiprocess_both.py", line 129, in dyn_lca
    timeline=dynamic_lca.calculate()
  File "/home/giuseppec/miniconda3/envs/bw2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bw2temporalis/dynamic_lca.py", line 54, in calculate
    **self.gt_kwargs
  File "/home/giuseppec/miniconda3/envs/bw2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bw2calc/graph_traversal.py", line 44, in calculate
    lca, supply, score = self.build_lca(demand, method)
  File "/home/giuseppec/miniconda3/envs/bw2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bw2calc/graph_traversal.py", line 107, in build_lca
    lca.decompose_technosphere()
  File "/home/giuseppec/miniconda3/envs/bw2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bw2calc/lca.py", line 216, in decompose_technosphere
    self.solver = factorized(self.technosphere_matrix.tocsc())
  File "/home/giuseppec/miniconda3/envs/bw2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py", line 377, in factorized
    return splu(A).solve
  File "/home/giuseppec/miniconda3/envs/bw2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py", line 257, in splu
    ilu=False, options=_options)
MemoryError
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multiprocess_both.py", line 181, in <module>
    dyn_multi=[x for x in pool_dyn_multi.get()] 
  File "/home/giuseppec/miniconda3/envs/bw2/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
MemoryError
```

it seems that scipy runs out of memory during the matrix inversion (I am certainly not the most knowledgeable to say this but I searched a bit around)
I just tried to install scikit-umfpack to see if something change....it is running but still seems to be painfully slow and not very promising and furthermore just return this warning:

```
Warning: (almost) singular matrix! (estimated cond. number: 3.33e+14)
```

actually do not have any idea on how to deal with this...anyone has?

P.S:I posted here since it looks to me not a bug of bw2, if so will open a issue

Answer (score 0):

What is your pool size? Probably the easiest thing to try is reduce the number of jobs running in parallel but setting the number of cpus to something like half as many as available.

It is also possible that there is a memory leak somewhere, and memory isn't being freed after a job finishes. You can sidestep this by setting `maxtasksperchild=1` when [constructing a MP Pool](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool).